# ¿Porque no me funciona la geolocalizacion con el package Laravel- farhanwazir laravelgooglemaps?

Tags: laravel, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

espero se encuentren bien, tengo un problema, estoy intentando mostrar en un mapa de google maps, cierta ubicacion (cualquiera la verdad), usando el package farhanwazir/laravelgooglemaps, el mapa se ve perfectamente pero no me muestra la ubicacion que escribo, siempre muestra el mismo lugar (algun lugar del atlantico sur), insertando las coordenadas funcionan bien, pero segun la documentacion del package tambien deberia de funcionar con una direccion, en mi cuenta de google tengo las siguientes APIs habilitadas:

- Directions Api
- Geocoding Api
- Geolocation Api
- Maps JavaScript Api
- Places Api.

Alguien sabe porque me pasa esto?. Aqui mi codigo:

ruta:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $config = array();
    $config['center'] ="Clifton, Karachi";
    $config['zoom'] = "5";
    $config['map_height'] = "500px";
    $config["scrollwheel"] = true;


    $gmap = new GMaps();
    $gmap->initialize($config);
    
    $marker["position"] = "Air Canada Centre, Toronto";
    $marker["infowindow_content"] = "Air Canada Centre, Toronto";
    $gmap->add_marker($marker);
    $map = $gmap->create_map();


    return view('welcome')->with("map", $map);
});
```

Vista:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        {!! $map["js"] !!}
    </head>
    <body>


        {!! $map["html"] !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

El marcador igual se coloca en la misma posicion del mar atlantico sur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion era añadir la key en cierta linea de codigo en el archivo GMaps.php:

Como estaba al principio:

```
$data_location = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode(utf8_encode($address))."&sensor=".$this->sensor;
```

Como se debe dejar:

```
$data_location = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode(utf8_encode($address))."&sensor=".$this->sensor."&key=".$this->apiKey;
```